# Why doesn't this work: $("body div button")[0].css

Tags: jquery

Given this HTML:

```
<div id="flashcard-001" class="flashcard">
    <div class="question">What color is the sky?</div>
    <div class="answer">blue</div>
    <button class="show">Show</button>
    <button class="hide">Hide</button>
</div>
```

This works:

```
$("div")[1].innerHTML = "What color is an apple?";
$("div")[2].innerHTML = '<span style="font-size:48pt;color:red">red</span>';
```

And this works (both buttons turn red):

```
$("body div button").css('background-color', 'red');
```

So why doesn't this work (first button does not turn red as expected):

```
$("body div button")[0].css('background-color', 'red');
```

Comment: You might want to see if you can give a best answer checkmark to about half of the questions you have asked.

Comment: 52% is about half actually :-) but you are right, I do often go back and try to up my 52% score on old questions since I truly appreciate answers but on many questions there really is no answer and marking one as the answer may give out points to someone but would be misleading to people who find the question and should really just read all the answers to get a general idea on what people think since there really is no correct answer, I do almost always give points to answers I find insightful or useful in some way though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As others already pointed out, when you use bracket syntax, you are accessing the actual DOM element not the jQuery object.

Try

```
$("body div button").eq(0).css('background-color', 'red');
```

or even better

```
$("body div button:first").css('background-color', 'red');
```

Answer (score 2):

When you specify [0] after a jQuery object you are accessing the direct DOM element, and DOM elements do not have a 'css' method defined ( [reference](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#ID-745549614) ). The css method works on jQuery objects because it is defined in the jQuery.prototype and all jQuery objects inherit that method, which is why:

$('body').css('background', 'red')

Works, and $('body')[0].css will throw an error.

Answer (score 2):

If you did:

```
$("body div button")[0].cssText = 'background-color', 'red';
```

That should work.

When you use [0] then you are looking at the DOM object, so at that point you can't use the jQuery helper functions but just go directly to the dom properties.

Comment: I think you mean `$("body div button")[0].cssText += 'background-color: red';`

Comment: Depends if he is replacing or appending to the css, but you could be right that it should be +=.

Answer (score 0):

use instead:

```
$("body div button:first").css(...
```

see [here](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/first)

Comment: Who is downvoting this? It's perfectly valid answer.

Comment: omg downvoted for the being the first to supply the accepted answer!?? *eyeroll*